LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli in Flutter
I recently updated my MacOS to Sonoma 14.4.1. I am using Flutter in Visual Studio Code. However, after updating I started getting errors when I ran the "flutter doctor" command in the terminal. That error was related to the Android license. After running "flutter doctor --android-licenses", I got the following error. 
After googling, I realized that this message is related to Java JDK. I tried to install Java Runtime 17 because class version 61 is related to Java Runtime 17. However, I was still getting the error. Then I also used homebrew to install Java Runtime 17 and correct "JAVA_HOME" path but that error exists. Then I realized that there are OpenJDK versions were installed. Now, I do not know how to delete them or how to remove these errors. If I run "Java --version" on mac terminal, it shows "openjdk 11.0.23" installed. However, on Visual Studio Code it shows "openjdk 17.0.11". I deleted all Java versions from "JavaVirtualMachine" folder and tried all other things. For example, installing Android SDK command-line tools. However, openjdk versions are still installed. Anybody can help please? 
